# Я не могу получить "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request" когда отправляю плохой пакет на сервер

Tags: python, сокет

Для теста мне надо кидать испорченный пакет на сервер и забирать ответ.
Делаю я это так:

```
pack = open('testPack', 'rb').read()

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('192.xxx.xx.xx', xxxxx))
sock.sendall(pack)

data = sock.recv(1024).decode("utf-8", errors="replace")
sock.close()
print(data)
```

**Проблема**: и все бы нормально, 200е и 500е я получаю сразу, но когда должен прийти 400 выполнение зависает на несколько минут(!) а потом выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "M:/assistant/pyTestAs/test", line 62, in <module>
    data = sock.recv(1024).decode("utf-8", errors="replace")
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
```

**Вопрос**: подскажите пожалуйста то нужно сделать что бы получить "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request"?

Comment: Request у вас является "не полный", а не "плохой" поэтому сервак висит и ждет пока вы дадите "полный". Что б Request считался полным, сделайте два возврата каретки `\r\n\r\n` хотя бы.

Comment: Большое спасибо что отозвались, но я тупой) Подскажите а в какое место в коде надо вставить ''\r\n\r\n"? Чтот у меня не получилось(

Comment: `pack += b"\r\n\r\n"`.

Comment: К сожалению не помогло(
Сделал так:
pack = open('testPack', 'rb').read()

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('192.xxx.xx.xx', xxxxx))
sock.sendall(pack + b'\r\n\r\n')

data = sock.recv(1024).decode("utf-8", errors="replace")
sock.close()
print(data) 
)

Comment: К сожелению нет чёткого определения в каком случае генерировать 400, поэтому - нужны спец-фильтры плохих запросов, либо надо что-то донастроить в web-сервере. (спец - потому что web-модули и web-приложения обрабатывают уже "принятый" запрос) В зависимости от типа сервера (Apach, nginx,  IIS) может быть тот или иной ответ. Максимум чем я могу "помочь", это сказать что возвращает мой IIS. Я всётаки полагаю что ваша проблема - серверная - нужно либо искать нормальный сервер, либо надо изучать ваш, позволяет ли он отбрасывать такие плохие запросы.

Comment: Как вариант, возможно `open('test Pack', 'rb').read() + b"\r\n\r\n"`  вставка пробела даст ответ (по аналогии с `GET /`)